# Python Multiprocessing and global variables

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing, global

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

b = {
        'x':{
            'd':[]
            },
        'y':{
            'd':[]
            },
}

def fmt():
    global b
    for k in b:
        if not b[k]['d']:
            b[k]['d'].append("fb1")
        print b
        t = Process(target=fb2, args=(k,))
        t.daemon = False
        t.start()

def fb2(k="x"):
    print os.getpid(), k, b[k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fmt()
```

Windows output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/qchen/PycharmProjects/syntax_test/syntax_test.py
{'y': {'d': ['fb1']}, 'x': {'d': []}}
{'y': {'d': ['fb1']}, 'x': {'d': ['fb1']}}
4412 y {'d': []}
5972 x {'d': []}
```

Linux Output:

```
qchen@ubuntu:~/PycharmProjects/for_test$ python syntax_test.py 
{'y': {'d': ['fb1']}, 'x': {'d': []}}
{'y': {'d': ['fb1']}, 'x': {'d': ['fb1']}}    
23547 y {'d': ['fb1']}
23548 x {'d': ['fb1']}
```

I don't know why it is different between Windows OS and Linux OS;
The difference is because of the difference of Process Fork and management in two OS

Comment: Why are you using global variables in the first place? Don't be that guy.

Comment: Looks like on Linux you printed `b[k]` (despite your code) while on Windows you really printed `b` (as the code states).  Since there is a difference in the used code (at least that's the simplest explanation), you probably messed up sth else.  I propose to compare both versions you run on the two systems, remove all differences, and retry that experiment.  Probably the peculiarities are gone then.

Comment: To *test* on Linux, you could use [Python 3.4 and `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) to avoid `fork`-semantics.

Comment: `global b` is useless unless there is `b = ..` in the function (or other binding statement)

Comment: The first print is my mistake;

Comment: This statement " b[k]['d'].append("fb1")" is not the binding statement??

Comment: @Wen_happiness: no. It doesn't bind any object to any name. Here some binding statements: `b = 1` (`b` refers to `1` (int object)), `import os as b` (`b` refers to `os` module`), `def b(): pass` (`b` refers to the function), `class b: pass` (`b` refers to the class). See [Naming and Binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the code behave similar on both Windows and Linux, pass `b` explicitly:

```
Process(target=fb2, args=(k, b))
```

The difference is that on Linux `fork` is used by default and it copies whatever state the parent process had to the child process. That is why the changes made inside `fmt()` are visible in children.

Windows uses `spawn` start method by default that reproduces the global state only partially e.g., values that are set during the import time are visible but changes made inside `fmt()` are not.